# Search Système Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, search, twig

Hello I shall like creating a system of search on my blog except that it does not work! I made this code I have an error of this type:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

If you have a solution for me help that shall be nice thank you very much!
my code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/recherche")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function search(Request $request): Response
{

    $info = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(InfoMore::class)->findByInfo(2);


    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $contentOfUsers = $form->getData();

        $contentOfUsers['name'];

        $search = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Articles::class)->findBysearch($contentOfUsers);

        return $this->render('backOffice/search/resultat.html.twig', [
            'resultatOfSearch' => $search,
            'info' => $info
        ]);

    }

    return $this->render('backOffice/search/search.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

my formType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'maxlength' => '30',
                    'minlength' => '3',
                    'label' => 'nom'
                ],
                'constraints' => [ new Assert\Length([
                    'min' => '2',
                    'minMessage' => 'Votre nom doit contenir au minimum {{ limit }} caractères.',
                    'max' => '30',
                    'minMessage' => 'Votre nom ne doit pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères.'
                ])]
            ])
        ;
    }
```

My Repository:

```
/**
 * @param $contentOfUsers
 * @return array
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function findBysearch(array $contentOfUsers) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('r')
        ->where('r.nameArticle LIKE :chaine')
        ->setParameter(':chaine', $contentOfUsers)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

my views :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and resultat :

```
{% for search in resultatOfSearch %}

    {{ search.resultatOfSearch }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ContentOfUsers should be array of article names?

In your controller you got line  $contentOfUsers['name']; -> wtf is this? Shouldn't be $contentOfUsers = $contentOfUsers['name'] and then you pass that name to rep and search article with the same name using = not like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax in findBysearch

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
$queryBuilder->select('r')
      ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->like('r.nameArticle', ':chaine'))
      ->setParameter('chaine', '%' . $contentOfUsers . '%');
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I missed the ; at the end. Was that it?

Comment: No no no, setParameter first argument doesn't need :

You need to use : only in where statement.

Comment: I fixed the param as rev pointed out. Did the error change when you used the code above?

Comment: I removed the first where. I forgot it there. Also try to add the wildcard character % before and after your search text. I made a modification to the code above

Answer (score 3):

In your repository, you don't have to specify the `:` in the `setParameter` method.

Replace the line by this one:

```
->setParameter('chaine', $contentOfUsers)
```

You can check the [official doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) on parameters binding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that does not still work ! That returns me the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to query on a whole array instead a a single value in

```
public function findBysearch(array $contentOfUsers) {
```

Try changing it so your argument is a single value. You can set the parameter in your controller like so `$value = $contentOfUsers['name'];` and then

```
public function findBysearch($value) {
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->select('r')
    ->where('r.nameArticle LIKE :value')
    ->setParameter('value', $value)
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help is working but i dont have result in my views i have for in result

Comment: @CrownBackend, I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your solution I do not work have no result ! I have no error but no result which displays on my view

Comment: In your controller you have to set a variable for `$contentOfUsers['name']` (like `$value = $contentOfUsers['name'];`) and then call that variable in your query like so: `->findBysearch($value)`. All of this is in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have same things in my controller but I have no result

Comment: If you are not searching for the exact name, but a part of it you can put this in your repo: 
           `->setParameter('value', '%'.$value.'%')`

Comment: I have an error of this type = Invalid parameter: token value is not defined in the query

Comment: I'm guessing this is because no information was put into the form to start with. So above your 'if form is valid' etc.. put `$value = null`.

Comment: Here ? : $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $value = null;

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

Comment: Yes, anywhere before the form.

Comment: When I remove "return $query->getResult();" in the repository It works but that shows me no result